# JS Timer is not starting when button pushed

Tags: javascript, timer

I have been looking at this for a few hours and cant seem to see why my code isnt starting the timer countdown when the button is pressed. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

HTML

```
<div id="timerHours">00</div>
<div id="timerMins">00</div>
<div id="timerSecs">00</div>
<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="startTimer()"/>
```

JavaScript

```
var t;
var timerDefault = new Date();
timerDefault.setHours(0, 0, 0);

function setTimer(){
    var element = document.getElementById("timerHours");
    hours = parseFloat(element.innerHTML);
    element = document.getElementById("timerMins");
    minutes = parseFloat(element.innerHTML);
    element = document.getElementById("timerSecs");
    seconds = parseFloat(element.innerHTML);
    timerDefault.setHours(hours, minutes, seconds);
}

function startTimer() {
    setTimer();
    var h = timerDefault.getHours();
    var m = timerDefault.getMinutes();
    var s = timerDefault.getSeconds();
    h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
    m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
    s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;
    document.getElementById("timerHours").innerHTML = h;
    document.getElementById("timerMins").innerHTML = m;
    document.getElementById("timerSecs").innerHTML = s;
    timerDefault.setSeconds(timerDefault.getSeconds() - 1);
    if (h == 0 && m == 0 && s == 0) clearTimeout(t)
    t = setTimeout(startTimer, 1000);
}
```

Comment: [It works just fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/LSDnd/)  The numbers don't change, but the code you've got never changes the numbers so that's not surprising.

Comment: Make sure you check the JavaScript error console, of course. If that code is inside a "load" handler or something, then it won't work because "startTimer" would be local to that function.

Answer (score 1):

Your "startTimer()" routine always calls "setTimer()", which (re-)initializes that Date object based on the contents of the HTML elements. The routine then backs the seconds down by 1, but it never updates the HTML. Thus, the next time the timer goes off, the Date instance ("timerDefault") is reset to 00:00:00.

Comment: I tried taking it out...and changed the variables...still doesnt work.

Comment: It works in the jsfiddle link I posted: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LSDnd/).  You can tell if you bring up the console.

Comment: @MrNart It definitely works. Are you seeing the "console.log()" output in your browser's console? Like I wrote, it does not change the document because your code simply does not do that properly.

Comment: I changed the values of the divs and tried to run it and it was not counting down.

Comment: It does not count down because your timer code resets the Date instance to the *current* value of the DOM elements on each iteration. You need to update the DOM after you subtract 1 from the "seconds" value.

Comment: I took out the setTimer() that was the issue at first, but it still doesnt run. Ill play with it some more until I figure it out.

Comment: I fixed it!!

I added setTimer() to onlick as well and removed it from the startTimer function, now its working!! Thanks again everyone!

http://jsfiddle.net/LSDnd/3/

Answer (score 0):

With a couple changes to your code you can see it count down a bit.

```
<div id="timerHours">00</div>
<div id="timerMins">00</div>
<div id="timerSecs">50</div>
<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="startTimer()"/>


var t;
var timerDefault = new Date();
timerDefault.setHours(0, 0, 0);

function setTimer(){
    var element = document.getElementById("timerHours");
    hours = parseFloat(element.innerHTML);
    element = document.getElementById("timerMins");
    minutes = parseFloat(element.innerHTML);
    element = document.getElementById("timerSecs");
    seconds = parseFloat(element.innerHTML);
    timerDefault.setHours(hours, minutes, seconds);
}

function startTimer() {
    setTimer();
    timerDefault.setSeconds(timerDefault.getSeconds() - 1);
    var h = timerDefault.getHours();
    var m = timerDefault.getMinutes();
    var s = timerDefault.getSeconds();
    console.log("Hi! " + h + " " + m + " " + s);
    h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
    m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
    s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;
    document.getElementById("timerHours").innerHTML = h;
    document.getElementById("timerMins").innerHTML = m;
    document.getElementById("timerSecs").innerHTML = s;
    if (h == 0 && m == 0 && s == 0) clearTimeout(t)
    t = setTimeout(startTimer, 1000);
}
```